# INSERT SQL error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

i have this in my script:

```
$db->q("INSERT INTO 'keys' (key,grupo,dias) VALUES ('$key','VIP',$love);");
```

which generates sql like this

```
INSERT INTO 'keys' ('key','grupo','dias') VALUES ('35F3','VIP',28)
```

but i get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''keys' ('key','grupo','dias') VALUES ('35F3','VIP',28)' at line
>   1

I'm adding screenshot of my table's structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luKfm.png

[image]

Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Interesting how your `key` column has no keys

Comment: Also, you may _potentially_ open to SQL Injection, depending on where `$key` and `$love` are coming from.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 3):

Tables names are identfiers not string literals. So in the case that they are escape, you should use backticks,

```
INSERT INTO `keys` (`key`,`grupo`,`dias`) VALUES ('35F3','VIP',28)
```

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)
- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List (*where backticks are applicable*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: You are so f**** fast it's unbelievable ... Do you get the questions before everyone else or something?? :)